# question about real analysis concerning inequality

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Suppose we have that $$a - \epsilon < F(x) < a + \epsilon$$

Does it follow that $a - \epsilon < F(x) \leq a $ ??

Comment: No. Why would it? Try a=3, epsilon=2, F(x)=4. (Unrelated: Please change your username, the current one is (childish and) derogatory.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

strip away the irrelevant context, and the question becomes: if $c \gt 0$ and $a \lt b+c$ does it follow that $a \le b$? why on earth should it???

on the other hand if OP's real question is this:

if $\forall c \gt 0$ we have $a \lt b+c$ does this imply $a \le b$ then the answer is: yes.

Comment: please take a look at my opinion

Answer (score 1):

In fact the symbolization $a\leq b$ means that

" $a$ is less **or** equal to $b$." $(1)$

(A proposition with **or**,let's say $p$= $p_1$or $p_2$ is true iff one at least off $p_i$'s is true)

Now in $(1)$ the two individual propositions cannot be true at the same time.This doesn't matter though because we need at least one in order to be true.So if we have that $a<b$ (strictly) then it is correct to say that $a\leq b$ because the proposition $(1)$ is true.

In this case though this symbolization is more of a rogue symbolization and try not to write $a\leq b$ when $a<b$.

Comment: your logic seems accurate to me, though i make many errors, so i would advise you to consult someone with more experience.